# Get the value of a JavaScript prompt box with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Imagine there is a button that opens up a JavaScript prompt box to show data to users and allow them to copy easily.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button id="show-coordinates" onclick="prompt('This is your coordinates', '4.684032, -74.109663');">
    Show Coordinates
  </button>
</body>

</html>
```

When automating the button using Selenium WebDriver, how to get the value of such prompt box (i.e. the coordinates in this case, need those values for further use)? WebDriver API provides a method to get the text of such prompt box (in this example, it's `This is your coordinates`), but not the value as far as I can see.

Native JavaScript solution can be considered too (not accessing the `onclick` attribute of `<button>` element of course. I put the event handler in DOM just to illustrate the problem easily).

```rb
driver.find_element(:id, 'show-coordinates').click
popup = driver.switch_to.alert
puts popup.text # This is your coordinates
# But how to get "4.684032, -74.109663"?
```

Comment: I wouldn't even bother. I'm not sure why you have a prohibition against accessing the `onclick` attribute. Check that it has the appropriate arguments passed to `prompt`. Otherwise, all you're doing is testing that the native browser's `prompt` method works. I assure you, the browser vendors have tested that themselves :).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Code above is just a simple example to illustrate the problem. Button's `onclick` event handler might not be in the DOM. The idea is get the coordinates for further use, not to test if they are there, therefore how browsers work seems irrelevant unfortunately. :( Selenium automates browsers, not necessarily just for testing purposes. Any other suggestions?

Comment: any idea how can i capture the value that is returned by user input?

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows only**

As you can see when prompt is opened required values in input field are selected (highlighted).  You can copy them and then use those values from clipboard. I tried common `selenium` methods to send `CTRL+C` combination, but it's not working as `find_element().send_keys()` and `switch_to_alert.send_keys()` seem to work differently...

So I used [Python AutoHotKey](https://pyahk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) + `win32clipboard`:

```
import win32clipboard
import time
import ahk
from selenium import webdriver

# Steps to open Prompt
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
driver.switch_to_alert()

# Copy prompt content
ahk.start()
ahk.ready()
ahk.execute("Send,^C") # sending CTRL + C
time.sleep(2) # Required... for some reason

driver.switch_to.alert.accept()

# Get values from clipboard
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

print(data) # Output is "4.684032, -74.109663"

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, using third party tools for OS/Browser level actions can be a solution. Upvoted.

Comment: any idea how can i capture the value that is returned by user input?